# how to hide an inside element in js dom

Tags: javascript, dom, hide, element

```
<p style="display:none">ppp<pre>123</pre></p>
```

this will show the text "123",My purpose is once I hide a element,all children will hide too,but why not?
In javascript,I can get the children of "p" tag and hide each one.it's too troublesome.
I want a simple way,like `"display:none;withChildren:all"` once and for all.
Is there any way?

Comment: It's your `<pre>` tag that's messing with your code. Try `<span>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<pre>` and `<p>` tag are both HTML block tags, which are not allowed to be nested inside of each other. Browser doesn't understand and render them separately, you can check by open developer tool to check the HTML code.

Instead, you should try using `<span>` or any inline-block tag.

Comment: inspect in chrome,even seems pre`s parentNode is not "p" but "body" why?

Comment: @nod as I explained, since both of them are not supposed to be nested together (block level tag), the browser can't render it, and weird behaviour will happen.

Comment: <pre style="display:inline"> or <pre style="display:inline-block">123</pre> 
 do not work too

Comment: @nod you get the problem wrong. Display: inline is extra css rendering. <pre> tag is an not an inline-level tag, but a block-level tag.

Comment: You can find the list of block-level tag here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/). For example.

```
$("p").children().hide(); // hide all children of `p`
$("p").hide(); // hide `p`
```

You could also use CSS selectors. Like so.

```
$("p *").hide(); // hide all children of `p`
$("p").hide(); // hide `p`
```

Comment: inspect in chrome,even seems pre`s parentNode is not "p" but "body" why?Can i use it without jquery?